# Send a variable to a Function when save button is clicked in the jQuery Dialog?

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have

```
<td>
    <?php $var=$arrayD[ 'Structural Data Loaded']; echo "<a data-id='$id' class='StructuralDataLoaded'>" . $var . "<img  id='$id' class='img' onclick='javascript:SelectStatus(id);' src='images/edit.png'></a>"; ?>
</td>
```

and

```
function SelectStatus(id) {

    var idvalue=id;
        console.log(idvalue); /* I can see the idvalue at console */
    var SelectingStatus = $('#SelectingStatus');
    SelectingStatus.dialog({
        close: function(event, ui) {

        },
        modal: true,
        title: 'id' ,
        width: 600,
        height: 'auto',
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        buttons: {
          'Save' : function PostStructuralDataLoadedData(idvalue){
    var data = $('#selected option:selected').val();
    console.log(idvalue);/* I can not see the idvalue at console */
    $(this).dialog('destroy');
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "InsertData.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
    id : idvalue,
    data : data,
    type : "StructuralDataLoladed"
    },
    dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function( ) {
    location.reload();
    });
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
},
          'Return': function(){$(this).dialog('destroy');}
      }

    });// End AddDocument dialog

}
```

When clicking on the Save button and calling PostStructuralDataLoadedData function, I want to send datavalue to that function,I wrote console.log(datavalue) in the PostStructuralDataLoadedData function, but I do not see anything in the console. How can I send datavalue to PostStructuralDataLoadedData function?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of id try to send the control as parameter to your function as below:

`onclick='javascript:SelectStatus(this)'`

and in your function

```
function SelectStatus(ctrl) {

    var idvalue=$(ctrl).attr('id'); //get the id attribute
    console.log(idvalue); 
    ........
    ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `$id` to `onclick='javascript:SelectStatus($id);` instead of `id` to `onclick='javascript:SelectStatus(id);'`

It should be -

```
<?php $var=$arrayD[ 'Structural Data Loaded']; echo "<a data-id='$id' class='StructuralDataLoaded'>" . $var . "<img  id='$id' class='img' onclick='javascript:SelectStatus('$id');' src='images/edit.png'></a>"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the solution and have posted it.  And for the section that you are talking about it also works when sending id.

Answer (score 0):

I found the soultion. So when I am calling PostStructuralDataLoadedData functionI shoudl cal it like:

```
       function PostStructuralDataLoadedData()
```

so have to remove idvalue.